# Ruby on Rails model method 'new' doesn't accept extra parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**UPDATE**

I answered my question below, but I am still asking for a prettier way to achieve my goal. I have a feeling my controller knows too much about *how to do things*.

---

I have a create action in my VideoController :

```
def create
  method = 'get_' + params[:video][:provider] + '_video_id'
  provider_video_id = Video.send(method, params[:video][:url])
  thumb = Video.get_thumb_from_youtube(provider_video_id)

  @video = Video.new(params[:video], :provider_video_id => provider_video_id, :thumb => thumb, :views => 0, :likes => 0)
  if @video.save!
    redirect_to video_path('1'), notice:'Video added successfully.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

I call Video.new with `params[:video]` with get its information from a form the user fills in. I then manipulate the URL the user passed in with the form to recover the `video_provider_id`and the`thumb`.

However, Rails is not saving the video with `provider_video_id`and `thumb`... I get this error on save :

`Validation failed: Thumb can't be blank, Thumb is invalid, Provider video can't be blank`

My guess is the `new`method doesn't accept extra parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I think Ruby on Rails' `new`method doesn't accept more than one parameter, which usually is `params`. What I did is I the following :

```
method = 'get_' + params[:video][:provider] + '_video_id'
params[:video][:provider_video_id] = Video.send(method, params[:video][:url])
params[:video][:thumb] = Video.get_thumb_from_youtube(params[:video][:provider_video_id])
params[:video][:views] = params[:video][:likes] = 0    

@video = Video.new(params[:video])
```

Now, it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

How about a before save callback in your model? This is an off-the-top-of-my-head default value example, but you could pass params in too.

```
after_initialize :url


private
def url
  self.provider_video_id ||= "default value"
end
```

Comment: Your solution seems good, but I'm not sure I understand it well. I need to call a method to get provider_video_id, so could I write : `self.provider_video_id = get_provider_video_id(params[:video][:url]`?

Answer (score 1):

But if you want, you can always override the default new action with something like

```
class Video 

   def new(attr1, attr2)
     super
     #do something with attr2
   end

end
```

Comment: Nice solution, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `.merge()`:

Instead of

```
method = 'get_' + params[:video][:provider] + '_video_id'
params[:video][:provider_video_id] = Video.send(method, params[:video][:url])
params[:video][:thumb] = Video.get_thumb_from_youtube(params[:video][:provider_video_id])
params[:video][:views] = params[:video][:likes] = 0    

@video = Video.new(params[:video])
```

You can do (modifying code from the original question):

```
@video = Video.new(params[:video].merge(:provider_video_id => provider_video_id, :thumb => thumb, :views => 0, :likes => 0))
```

That will merge the params into one hash.